# Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid self signed SSL

Tags: ssl, centos, yum, self-signed

my server A is a repo server with self-signed SSL enabled.
Now my server B  yum.repolist.d files are configured with server A (https)

```
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://10.120.0.130/CentOS/6/updates/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
sslverify=1
```

Now when I run yum repolist it give me error

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
https://10.120.0.130/CentOS/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
```

Now I dont want to sslverify=0/false. I want to trust the selfsigned SSL cert which I did based on the following link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509271/import-self-signed-certificate-in-redhat)

But I am still getting the error. Does anybody has any sollution.